# Methods for checking if a given number is prime or not .

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

We all know Wilson's theorem :

$n$ is prime if $\frac {\Gamma(n)+1}{n}$ is an integer .

We can call it a prime checking method .

There are other various trivial methods .

The main thing to notice about this method is that $\Gamma$ is analytic , but also inefficient ( as grows very rapidly )

Are there any similar method with analytic flavor to it which can be more efficient than this one ?

Comment: It is known that $n$ is prime iff $\dbinom nk$ is a multiple of $n$ for all $1\le k\le n-1$. And it suffices to check it for $2\le k <\dfrac{n+1}2$. I don't know if this idea can be improved to make it more efficient that your method.

Comment: At the page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test you will find all information you need.